# Reading EPUB files from device in Windows Mobile in Xamarin C#

Tags: wpf, xamarin, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, epub

I am trying to locate EPUB files on a windows phone and after user selects one file, I have to display it in a WebView and provide features such as changing font size, color, searching etc.

I have made the user select an EPUB file so far, but am now looking for a library to open the file and read contents. I have looked at several libraries on NuGet (VersFx, EpubSharp, Epubreader.cross, epubreader) without any luck.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to achieve it using EpubReader.cross for WP8.1.
Got the package from Nuget and used the following code.

```
Stream _tempStream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();

var _book = EpubReader.ReadBook(_tempStream)
```